# In the phrase “collaborative learning partnerships,” is the word “learning” a verb, noun, article or adjective?

Tags: grammar

How do I decide if a word ending in -ing is verb, noun, article or adjective?

Comment: Hello! This is an interesting question for English learners, but we expect to see a description of the research that you've done. If you've already looked in a dictionary, then it would be useful to say which part of speech you think might work and why. That will greatly help us to understand your confusion and provide useful answers.

Comment: Please put the question in the body of the question, and a short summary in the title.  Don't try to put the question in the title and your biography in the body.

Answer (score 1):

"collaborative learning partnerships”

Articles (a, an, and the) are ruled out; verbs are out too as *collaborative* cannot be doing the learning.

*learning* modifies *partnerships*.  It, however, is not a present participle (traditional name).  The partnerships are unlikely to be doing the learning though they collaborate/ promote/ facilitate learning for members.

*learning* is what was traditionally called a gerund.  It is an attributive noun and functions as an adjective.

In modern grammar, verb+ing words are called gerund-participles.

Comment: Thank you Seowjooheng Singapore.